# Maven Spring Boot -- Getting "package does not exist" error for multi-module provider package

Tags: spring-boot, maven

Been going in many circles here trying to figure out what seemed like a trivial case.

Have simple Maven multi-module composite project (parentz has children providerz and dependentz)

**pom.xml (parentz)**

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>    
    <relativePath />
</parent> 
<groupId>parentz</groupId>
<artifactId>parentz</artifactId>
<version>0.0.0</version>
<packaging>pom</packaging>
...
```

**pom.xml (providerz)**

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>parentz</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
</parent>  
<artifactId>providerz</artifactId>
<name>providerz</name>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>    
...
```

**pom.xml (dependentz)**

```
...
<parent>
    <groupId>parentz</groupId>
    <artifactId>parentz</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.0</version>
</parent>  
<artifactId>dependentz</artifactId>
<name>dependentz</name>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<packaging>war</packaging> 
...
<dependency>
    <groupId>parentz</groupId>
    <artifactId>providerz</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>   
...
```

---

**Code:**

This public class is in the providerz module:

```
com.shapes.model.Rec
```

This public class is in the dependentz module:

```
com.shapesui.model.RecController

And it imports from the provider:

import com.shapes.model.Rec;    <-- FAILURE POINT
```

---

**Execution and Error**

**Provider Project (OKAY):**

```
>mvn -am -pl providerz clean install
```

BUILD SUCCESS

**Dependent Project (FAILS):**

```
>mvn -am -pl dependentz clean package
```

[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile)
on project dependentz: Compilation failure
[ERROR] ... ShapesParent/dependentz/src/main/java/com/shapesui/controller/RecController.java:[12,24] 
package com.shapes.model does not exist

So the bottom line is that the dependent it seems cannot reference packages in the provider:

**package com.shapes.model does not exist**

Comment: Found one last article I had not yet read and it seems to have a solution that repackages and produces second jar "-task.jar". Not yet clear on "why" (if anyone has insight that would be great). But seems to resolve the issue. Article is:  "https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/repackage-classifier.html".

Comment: Why does the parent of your project has a version `0.0.0` and your childs have `1.0.0` does not make sense in a multi module build?

Comment: Just followed some example. Thx for pointing out. Not related to problem but helpful feedback.

Comment: This example "https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/" has five modules and of course I expected the main model class (e.g. Employee) to be reused, but the class is actually duplicated in each module.

Comment: If you a separate module which you publish via `mvn clean deploy` in a repository each one can consume each module of it...cause each module has a unique groupId/artifactId/version ....